# Properties and accessor methods without member in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, member, accessor

I was just going through properties documentation in the link:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html 
The section' You Can Implement Custom Accessor Methods' describes that Properties don’t always have to be backed by their own instance variables. The example of fullName also does not use its own corresponding member.

Won't the compiler implicitly create a member when a property is defined (_propertyName)?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a property using `@property`, then an ivar is created automatically and its setter and getters are created by LLVM compiler.

Whereas when you create an ivar, you have to create a setter/getter for it. Typically you do with `@property` and leave rest on the compiler.

However in some cases you create ivar and property with different name and put a reference to it as :

```
@synthesize boxDescription=boxName;
```

Now boxName is accessor for boxDescription, now you cant use `boxDescription` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My question is different. Suppose I declare @property(nonatomic)NSString *fullName in header file and I do not declare any member for fullName. In source file I don't write synthesize fullName and implement a accessor method fullName { return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"myFirstName", @" ", @"myLastName"] }. In this case will the compiler automatically define a member _fullName?

Comment: If you use new compiler, only writing `@property(nonatomic)NSString *fullName`  creates setter/getter for it and it default to `_fullName`. So you are overriding by creating your accessors.

Answer (score 0):

if you override the default setter and getter, and you dont provide the @synthesize (and as well you dont access the _ivar), no variable is created for you by the compiler. in that case you have a property that is not backed by an ivar.

as a very random example:

```
@property (nonatomic) int x;

- (int)x
{
  return 1;
}

- (void)setX:(int)x
{
  NSLog(@"%d", x);
}
```

a more userfull usage can be if you have a facade for other classes, and you use this setter/getter to set/get those.

in case you don't override the set/getter and now that @synthesize is not mandatory anymore by default the compiler creates an ivar named _propertyname, you can override this behavious by `@synthesize prop_name=ivar_name`